# Golang: Is there any way to access the "child" struct in the "parent" struct's methods in Go's composition model?

Tags: oop, orm, go

I want to make a generic model struct to embed in structs that will use `gorp` (https://github.com/coopernurse/gorp) to persist objects in my MySQL database.  It's my understanding that this kind of composition is how one accomplishes things in Go that are done with inheritance in strongly OO languages.

I haven't been having good luck, however, as I want to define all of the CRUD methods on the `GorpModel` struct, to avoid repeating them in each model, but this causes `gorp` (as I'm using it right now) to assume that the table I want to interact with is called `GorpModel` due to the reflection that `gorp` uses.  Which causes errors, naturally, as I have no such table in my database.

Is there any way to figure out / use which type I'm in (the superclass which `GorpModel` is embedded in) to make the below code work, or am I barking up the wrong tree altogether?

```
package models

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "github.com/coopernurse/gorp"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type GorpModel struct {
    New            bool   `db:"-"`
}

var dbm *gorp.DbMap = nil

func (gm *GorpModel) DbInit() {
    gm.New = true
    if dbm == nil {
        db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "username:password@my_db")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        } 
        dbm = &gorp.DbMap{Db: db, Dialect: gorp.MySQLDialect{"InnoDB", "UTF8"}}
        dbm.AddTable(User{}).SetKeys(true, "Id")
        dbm.CreateTables()
    }           
}

func (gm *GorpModel) Create() {
    err := dbm.Insert(gm)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func (gm *GorpModel) Delete() int64 {
    nrows, err := dbm.Delete(gm)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return nrows
}   

func (gm *GorpModel) Update() {
    _, err := dbm.Update(gm)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } 
}
```

The `New` property of the `GorpModel` struct is used to keep track of whether it is a newly created model, and whether we should call `Update` or `Insert` on `Save` (which is defined in the child `User` struct at the moment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to figure out / use which type I'm in (the superclass which GorpModel is embedded in)

No.

I don't know the best way to structure your solution, but with respect to the CRUD you're trying to implement in some kind of base class, just write them as functions. ie.

```
func Create(gm interface{}) { // or whatever the signature should be
    err := dbm.Insert(gm)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you good sir.  This ends up working pretty well for my needs at the moment.